# Hide Tooltip Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

i want to hide the tooltip showing when hovering on this element (using Materialize CSS)

```
<li><a class="btn-floating green" onclick="window.print();return false;"><i class="material-icons tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Print schedule">print</i></a></li>
```

The problem is that when i click on the button, it immediately shows the print layer and i see the tooltip on the printed page (it'll be printed with the page).
i want to hide the tooltip when i click on the print button. 

thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing the `tooltippped` class from the `<i>` tag?

Comment: If i remove i can no longer see it when i hover on the button, i want to hide only when i click on print.

Answer (score 3):

Using the close command on the tooltip worked for me:

`$('.tooltipped').tooltip('close');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this, it works for me.

```
  $('#search_button').click(function(){ 

        // hide all tooltips
        $('.tooltipped').tooltip('close');

        // now you must re-open tooltip, otherwise, it will stay close state
        $('.tooltipped').tooltip(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tooltipped` class

```
<li>
 <a class="btn-floating green" onclick="window.print();return false;">
  <i class="material-icons" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Print schedule">print</i>
 </a>
</li>
```

Comment: If i remove i can no longer see it when i hover on the button, i want to hide only when i click on print.

Comment: Class 'tooltipped' used for selector ONLY. If you do so AFTER your page is loaded and tooltipped elements are configured as tooltipped - removing the class will not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try both or any one of them:

```
//for right or left click(any)
$('.tooltipped').mousedown(function(){
  $('.material-tooltip').css("visibility", "hidden");
});

// leaving after click in case you open link in new tab
$('.tooltipped').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.material-tooltip').css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JS interferes with the CSS, I suggest using the events `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint